# Changes in browser are showing up in the server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Sorry for my bad English.

I have this little part of my code that gets a value from a Servlet and i show it.

```
<form method="post" action="rent">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Office Number: ${o.id}</h4>
        <input type="hidden" value="${o.id}" name="officenumber">
    </div>
</form>
```

To be able to get that value and send it to another servlet i use an input with hidden type. Then, i catch it in my servlet

```
int officenumber = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("officenumber"));
RequestDispatcher rd;
request.setAttribute("officenumber ", officenumber );
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/rent.jsp");   
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Then i show it in a new JSP. The problem is that everybody can use "*Inspect Element*" tool, change the value from my hidden input and the new inserted value will be sended.

Is it anyway to avoid that?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's why you should not rely on elements coming from the client.
there must be a verification done on server.
i suggest reading on putting the logged-in user's id on session, 
and when receiving a request, you need to make sure the office-id belongs to the user, and the user has permissions to change/ delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely store the "hidden input" on server side and should not let the user send that value to you. If you need the user to send the value for some reasons, you should authenticate the user (login, password, pin, or any method) and then validate the value that is given to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack in such case. What you can do is provide a Encoding of text for parameter named `officenumber` at client side. Later decode that text at server-side.

You can apply rules from [OWASP cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) as per you requirement.

By doing this, Even though the value is changed at client side it will not harm/break your server side code.

**Note:** Anyone change the value of input parameters of a form before submitting it, So its a developer's responsibility to provide security to the code/Application.